# How to clone local repository

Tags: command-line, git

I have two folders sitting next to each other on my machine.

- `/Documents/Learning/Project1`
- `/Documents/Learning/Test for git`

`Project1` has a local repository inside with one commit on it, and I'd like to copy it to the other folder. I'm running the commands:

```
/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1 .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1.git .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1.git .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1/.git .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1 .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1 .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1.git .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1/git .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist

/Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /Documents/Learning/Project1/.git .
fatal: repository '/Documents/Learning/Project1' does not exist
```

But I keep getting an error saying repository doesn't exist, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository is not in `/Documents/Learning/Project1`. It's in `/home/<your username>/Documents/Learning/Project1`. You could also use the shortcut `~/Documents/Learning/Project1`.

Note that you can't git clone into an existing (non-empty) directory, so you should delete `~/Documents/Learning/Test for git` and your command should be (**assuming your current working directory is `~/Documents/Learning/`**):

```
$ git clone ~/Documents/Learning/Project1/ ./Test\ for\ git/
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. As for cloning into a existing repository I just used          /Documents/Learning/Test for git$ git clone /home/kyle/Documents/Learning/Project1/.git . apparently the . at the end lets you copy it to the directory your currently in.

Comment: My bad. You can git clone into an existing empty directory.